# What's Apple's term for horizontal "swipeable bar"?

Tags: interaction-design, ios, touch-screen, drag-n-drop, gestures

[image: Screenshots from the requested UI element]

I'm looking for the term of the UI element Apple is using pretty often lately. On iPads you can see them on the top of windows to symbolize that the user can drag this. On the iPhone X it replaced the home button.
I started to use this also and I don't know how I should call it and on Apple's documentation I couldn't find anything about this. It kinda reminds me of a pill or something.

Comment: Apple doesn't seem to give a specific name to this element. In fact, I'm not sure that it should be considered a swipeable bar, but rather a visual indicator for screen-edge gestures. This item tells you that content or actions can be displayed by swiping from this point. 

Source : https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/user-interaction/gestures/

Answer (score 1):

In its documentation, Apple seems to refer to these in vague words, as **indicators**. The bottom bar doesn't seem to have an official label. From [Daring Fireball](https://daringfireball.net/linked/2017/11/01/iphone-x-home-indicator):

> Apple seems to be going out of its way not to give the horizontal bar
>   at the bottom of the iPhone X user interface a name. For example, in
>   the “getting started” pamphlet that ships in the iPhone X box, they
>   don’t give it a name. They just show a picture of it, with an arrow
>   indicating the gesture, and say “Swipe up to go home.”
>
> Those of us who write about these things need a name for it, though. I
>   suggest “home indicator”. In Apple’s Human Interface Guidelines for
>   iPhone X, they use a similar but more verbose construction: “the
>   indicator for accessing the Home screen”.
>
> UPDATE: It’s also called the home “indicator” in the UIKit APIs.
>   (Thanks to Sachin Patel.)

Comment: So, "home indicator" seem to be the closest one. But since its not just for the home gesture maybe "swipe indicator" should be the more general term? Even though it's not very specific...

Comment: Yup, swipe indicator was what I was thinking, too. That said, there just doesn't seem to be an official term yet.